# How to remove string after and before specific chars

Tags: string, typescript, replace, char, substring

I have this string: `https://2352353252142dsbxcs35@github.com/happy.git`

I want to get result: `https://github.com/happy.git` (without random string after second `/` and after `@` but without `@`).

Now I have something like this:

```
var s = 'https://2352353252142dsbxcs35@github.com/happy.git';
var d = s.substring(s.indexOf('/')+2, s.indexOf('@')+1;
s = s.replace(d, "");
```

it works, but I know it's an ugly solution.
What is the most efficient and more universal solution?

Comment: Will the number of characters in this link will be same or not ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj - no, random number of characters.

Comment: Hold on looks like I've found something. But confirm once, you just have to remove those random character right after `https://` and before `@github.com` ?

Comment: Check my answer, it worked for m perfectly. Do let me know how it works for you ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const indexOfAtSign: number = receivedMessage.indexOf('@')+1
const httpsString: string = 'https://'
const trimmedString: string = s.slice(indexOfAtSign)
const requiredURL: string = httpsString.concat(trimmedString)

// Print this value of requiredURL wherever you want.
```

So here what my code does is, it gets position of `@` and removes everything before it along with the sign itself. Then using the `slice()` function, we are left with the remaining part which I named as trimmedString. Now I have pre-defined the `https string, anf we just need to merge them now. Done :-)

I had tried this out in my telegram bot and here's how it works:

[image]